# Update Android Studio from previous Version

Tags: android, android-studio, proxy, http-proxy

Connection failed(Unable to tunnel through proxy).Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden").please check network connection and try again.

Why I am getting this error.My current version is 1.5 and on updating it gives this error.Is it a bug?I am able to access internet on my office network an dI think I have configured my proxy correctly.
I uninstalled my AS 1.5 and downloaded the fresh version AS 2.1.1 and then installed it but again if I try to check for updates by going to Help> Check for Updates  I get the same error.

I tried this both on Windows and Ubuntu 12.04.

[image: Android Studio Update Error ,update from 1.5]

Answer (score 1):

The link to update the android studio may be blocked by the network provider/admin Or it may be due to slow Internet connection(Congestion)

Try this
Goto File->setting->In appearence tab search for system setting->Http Proxy and disable it

Another Alternative is to disable offline mode.

Go to File -> Settings.

And open the 'Build,Execution,Deployment',Then open the 'Build Tools' -> 'Gradle'.

Then uncheck "Offline work" on the right.

Click the 'OK' button.

Then Rebuild the Project.

Comment: no proxy? for Android..Really?? now it gives "Connection failed(dl.google.com).Please check netowrk connection and try again?

Comment: I made small edit to my answer(disable offline mode).Try it

Answer (score 0):

File->Settings->Appearance and Behavior->System Settings->Updates

uncheck "Use secure connection"

If this check box is cleared, the HTTP protocol is used. By default, the check box is selected.